# Variables as object references not working

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = {};
var b = a;
b.c = "whatever";

console.log(a.c) // whatever.
```

**Work as expected, a can be updated by b;**

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
b = "whatever";

console.log(a) // {}
console.log(b) // whatever
```

**Not work as expected. a not updated by b**

## Update Question: Does it mean only object properties can be updated by its reference ? not for object itself ?

Comment: what do you expect as the answer ?

Comment: `b` is just a name that points to the actual object. In the first example, both `a` and `b` point to the same object. In the second example you change the object `b` points to from the `{}` that `a` also points to to a new string `"whatever"` This doesn't change `a` or the object `a` points to.

Comment: As soon as you override a variable, it's overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article about [Explaining Value vs Reference in Javascript](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0).

You have overrided the reference when you did:

```
 b = "whatever";
```

When you do this, `b` doesn't point to `a` anymore. Now, `b` has it own value. You just can update a property of the object referenced by b, like in your example:

```
b.c = "whatever";
```

Comment: does it mean only object properties can be updated by its reference ?. not for object itself ?.

Comment: @Kardinata exactly!

Comment: yeah. Because you reference to object.

Answer (score 2):

**This is how their values are stored in the memory:**

> First approach

```
         +-----+------+
Variable |  a  |   b  |
         +-----+---|--+
   Value | {}  |<--+  | //'b' points to 'a', so every change (to the object) 
         +-----+------+ // in 'b' will modify 'a'.
```

> Second approach

```
         +-----+---------+
Variable |  a  |   b     |
         +-----+---|-----+
   Value | {}  |<--+     | //First assignment.
         +-----+---------+
   Value | {}  | Whatever| //Second assignment.  So, you're only assigning a new    
         +-----+---------+ //value to 'b' and not modifying the previous  
                           //value (properties/fields) from 'a'.
```

Comment: Before new value asign for b, b asigned as a reference. I confused about why b is not also changes a ?!.

Comment: @Kardinata Like I said, you're assigning a new value to `b` and losing the reference of `a` so, you're modifying neither fields nor properties from `a`.

Answer (score 1):

By stating `b = "whatever";`, you have reassigned the variable `b` from referencing (sorry I dont know the exact term, therefore I am calling it 'referencing') the variable `a`, to a `string` which contains the value `"whatever"`, within it.

It is important to know that JavaScript is flexible when it comes to variable assignment, like most modern high-level programming languages today, as it allows you to not only change the value of an earlier declared variable, but also change the data type for that assigned variable, for example:

```
var x = "This is A string";
x = [] //Now the variable has been reassigned to an array.
x = {} //Now the variable has been reassigned to an object.
```

Therefore, if you are not careful with how you assign your variables, you can quite easily create errors, similar to the one you have expressed on your second approach.